# AWS load balancer size limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

The AWS ALB limits size to 100 MB.  Part of my API response is a rendered README.md from the Github API.  I don't control the rendering, but it turns out ALB will not return a response with text of this rendered REAME.md file from Github.  When I move response to directly hitting an Nginx LB from a VM, there is no issue.  I looked at content, and yes, the README content is fairly large it seems.  I don't know if/how exceeds 100 MB, but it seems to be he problem.  Regardless, I cannot control how Github controls the rendering.

Is there any workaround this 100 MB limit?  If not, can I use Nginx as a reverse load balancer for lambda functions?  Otherwise, I'll need to go back to regular VMs and do a weighted DNS among non-autoscaling VMs since I still can't use a load balancer for VMs, Fargate, or anything.

Comment: Lambda payload is max 6MB. How exactly the use of ALB or nginx would help you processing 100 MB files in lambda?

Comment: oh thanks!  maybe that's the issue.  maybe i can try fargate then.  i was thinking the readme can't be 100 mb.  super helpful.  let me move over to fargate and see if it works.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I will provide a short answer with some links.

Comment: Hi. How did it go? Still unclear why you had this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up and help!  It looks like you were right, the 6 MB size limit on lambda resulted in empty responses. Moving to fargate solved all the problems.  I love lambda, but fargate solved a lot of issues with empty responses and even response time.  The response time on fargate is like 2-3x faster than lambda even when I pre-provision lambda.  Not sure if i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments.

One can't upload 100 MB files into a lambda function directly. The reason is that max data payloads for the lambda [are](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html):

- 6 MB (synchronous)
- 256 KB (asynchronous)

The alternatives are:

- upload the file to S3 instead. You can setup S3 events to trigger your lambda for each newly uploaded file.
- use something else then lambda, EC2, Fargate or Beanstalk to be able to upload 100 MB files directly.

Comment: thanks for the info and help!  it's actually part of the return response.  i guess lambda just failed, but it's sort of hard to see in the logs. but it's been fixed with fargate!